# Convert Directory.GetFiles to Systems.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that I found whereby it uses a `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)` to populate an Array that is then used with a For Each statement.

This is to be populated with a `Directory.GetFiles(strFolderPath)`.

I can't seem to get the conversion to work properly can someone point me in the right direction.

I did:

```
Dim strAttachments As New StringCollection()
strAttachments.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(GlobalVariables.strFolderPath))
```

But I get

> Error 1   Value of type
>   'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection' cannot be converted
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of
>   String)'. C:\Users\JamesL.FRESHINSURANCE\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\Fresh eDoc System\Fresh eDoc
>   System\MainForm.vb    616 145 Fresh eDoc System

Comment: The first part of this question is somewhat confusing, your solution does not use a Generic List to populate an array, it uses an array to populate a generic list. Were you referencing a different method (a seperate consideration) all together there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that you want to use a `List(Of T)` and not a `StringCollection`:

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(GlobalVariables.strFolderPath)
Dim strAttachments As New List(Of String)(files)
```

Comment: Hi Tim.

Just solved it myself with the same line of code :D

Thanks buddy.